# Pipe communication between high privilege (service) and low privilege process (chrome sandbox process)

Tags: c, ipc, named-pipes

/* I want to do IPC between my service and low privilege processes like chrome sandbox, internet explorer etc.

I have injected my dll in such processes and from that injected dll, I am sending some data about the current process using PIPE, but the processes are low privileged and they cannot open my high security PIPE. One solution is make the PIPE with low security or accessible to everyone but I want to keep my PIPE more secure.*/

Comment: You could probably use a file and file permissions for security, or you could create a separate security daemon bridge process that handshakes with your low privileged code that is high privileged and has access to the pipe.

Comment: thank you @A.Danischewski, but my architecture does not allow for it. I want a solution with my existing architecture (low privileged process to service communication with high privilege pipe). Is there any way to secure my low privileged PIPE? Is there any existing system policy or feature which can be used for this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx